# Why do objects stick to the edge when their sign is reversed?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning a little bit of javascript and found that when you draw an object and want to set it to "bounce" off the border multiplying it (var *= -1) doesn't work. The object sticks to the border and stops moving.

In this example the ball reaches the top of the page and moves up and down repeatedly like it's "stuck" on the border:

```
    // position of the ball
var y = 0;
// how far the ball moves every time
var speed = 2;

draw = function() {
    background(127, 204, 255);

    fill(66, 66, 66);
    ellipse(200, y, 50, 50);

    // move the ball
    if (y > 375 || y < 25){
        speed *= -1;
    }
    y = y + speed;
};
```

Comment: you are learning "java" or "javascript"?

Comment: `0 < 25` ? ... ...

Comment: Your initial y should be between 25 and 375. Right now y will always be smaller than 25.

Comment: This comes from "Intro to JS: Drawing & Animation" on Khan Academy. Using JavaScript language and the ProcessingJS library.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of it being something so simple. Changing the start y to 25 fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

If the ball's y is either below 23 or greater than 377, inversing the speed will not get it into the accepted range again, and the direction will be inversed again, so it keeps jumping up and down. You could change the condition to:

```
 if (y > 375 && speed > 0 || // if reaching upper broder and moving up or
     y < 25 && speed < 0 // if reaching lower border and moving down
 ) speed *= -1;
```